# Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" found for Linear Layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-linearlayout, xml-namespaces

I am getting this error while creating my .xml file for customdialog in android app.

> Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" found for tag Linear Layout

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_gravity="center" 
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ImageView 
    ...
<ScrollView 
    ...
<LinearLayout 
    ...

  **xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">**
    <Button 
        ...
    <Button 
        ...
    <Button 
        ...
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: have you tried removing **xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">** you already gave it in the start

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the line you have already marked with stars:

```
**xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">**
```

(Well, you'll have to keep the `>`)

The xmlns tag should only be included in the outmost container.

Answer (score 0):

At that point in the XML, you're already in the scope of the first `xmlns:android` definition.  You shouldn't be defining it again.  Just delete that second definition and you'll be fine.